# Will using iptables DROP target cause TCP CLOSE_WAIT that never completes?

Tags: linux, networking, apache-http-server, firewall, iptables

I have some simple rules to block certain IP blocks used frequently by hackers/spammers, e.g.:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 173.208.250.0/24 -j DROP
```

But, I noticed that apache hangs after a couple of days with many CLOSE_WAITs showing in netstat output that never go away:

```
\# netstat -atlpn
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        1      0 ::ffff:10.0.0.107:80        ::ffff:63.141.243.26:50813  CLOSE_WAIT  29125/httpd
```

Could this be caused by specifying the DROP target in the rule?  Should I use REJECT instead?

Answer (score 1):

No. It means the far end has closed the connection but locally it hasn't been closed yet.

Dropping all traffic from a source means no connections from there will be established to being with.